# If decimals are zero ignore but if non-zero, read in the first two

Tags: c#

If decimals are zeros, ignore but non zero, need to read in the first two

```
"35.0" or "35.0000" = 35
"35.0193" = 35.01
"35.98759" = 35.98
```

Any ideas?

```
var splitSku4 = value.Split('.');
if (splitSku4.Length > 1)
{
    if (!splitSku4[1].StartsWith("0") || !splitSku4[1].StartsWith("00"))
    {
        sku4 = string.Format("{0}.{1}", splitSku4[0], splitSku4[1].Substring(0, 2));
    }
}
```

stuck at this point

Comment: Hello Peter, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then update your question accordingly.

Comment: Firstly, you will need some code. Have you written any? An example would help us understand the question. I have no idea what "read in" means, for example.

Comment: Format the value to 2 decimals and then compare them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string that contains a numeric value, you can convert it using one of the Convert methods (e.g. [Convert.ToDouble](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx)) or by using one of the Parse or TryParse methods associated with the target data type (e.g. [Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Examples:

```
var input = "35.98759";
var number = double.Parse(input);
```

Or

```
var number = Convert.ToDouble(input);
```

Once you have the value stored in a numeric data type, you can remove the least significant digits using [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var input = "35.98759";
var number = double.Parse(input);
var numberToTwoDecimals = Math.Round(number, 2);
```

If you always want to round downward, there are a few ways to do it, but the simplest in this case is to subtract 0.005 before rounding the number.

```
var result = Math.Round(number - 0.005F, 2);
```

Once the decimals are removed, you can convert back to a string if you want:

```
var outputString = result.ToString("0.00");
```

Result:

```
35.98
```

[Example code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zcvpaF)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
var number = 2.56832;
string newnumber = string.Format("{0:0.00}", number )); // formats to 2 decimal places
string[] split = newnumber.Split('.'); //split and remove '.'

if(Convert.ToInt16(split[1]) == 0){ //convert second index to number
    var final = split[0];
}else{
    var final = newnumber;
}
```

or in 1 line:

```
var number = 2.56832;
string newnumber = string.Format("{0:0.00}", number )); 
string[] split = newnumber.Split('.'); //split and remove '.'

var final = Convert.ToInt16(split[1]) == 0 ? split[0] : newnumber;
```

Comment: `or in 1 line` - I count 4 :)